# How to load text from Firebase in label?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, label

I need to load text from child "Nick"
every-time my program changes label text on void :(

this is my code:

```
  ref = Database.database().reference()
refHandle = ref.observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
    let dataDict = snapshot.value as! [String: AnyObject]
    print(dataDict)
})

let userID: String = (Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)!
ref.child("Users").child(userID).child("Nick").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { 
    snapshot in 
    print(snapshot)
    let m = snapshot.value as? String
    self.label.text = m
})
```

[And this is how my Firebase looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mENsn.png)

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: i need to load "mxm" in label. My code doesn't working

Comment: "My code doesn't working." That's **really** unhelpful.

Answer (score 0):

You have to take the value "Nick" from the snapshot value. So your code will look like this:

```
let userID: String = (Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)!
ref.child("Users").child(userID).child("Nick").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { 
    snapshot in 

    guard let value = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else { return }
    guard let name = value["Nick"] as? String else { return }

    let m = name
    self.label.text = m
})
```